# SQL: Get top element directly from join

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join, greatest-n-per-group

I'm quite interested in learning if we can avoid inner query and use join to get the top element of another table before join.

For instance take the example as, there is a table of "students" and another table representing "student_marks" which marks of student in individual subject.
Now for each student I want to list his highest mark among all subject.

```
student
-----------------------------
| student_id | name   | Age |
-----------------------------
| S1         | Biden  | 15  |
| S2         | Jordan | 16  |
-----------------------------

student_marks
-------------------------------------
| student_id | subject      | marks |
-------------------------------------
| S1         | Geology      | 80    |
| S1         | Trigonometry | 90    |
| S2         | Geography    | 70    |
| S2         | Geology      | 75    |
-------------------------------------
```

Desired result is something like below:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| student_id | name   | age | subject      | marks |
----------------------------------------------------
| S1         | Biden  | 15  | Trigonometry | 90    |
| S2         | Jordan | 16  | Geology      | 75    |
----------------------------------------------------
```

> Since I'm using MySql, I can't use with clause

My attempts are

```
select * from
student s
inner join (
    select student_id, max(marks) as marks from student_marks group by student_id
) max_student_marks sm
on s.student_id = sm.student_id;
```

PS: The above approach does give the desired result (without subject column), but runs really slow as the amount of data increases. So is there a better way of utilizing join and pick the top element from secondary table used for join.

Comment: 'Since I'm using MySql, I can't use with clause' - since version 8 you can..what version are you on?

Comment: I'm using 5.17 or 5.2 something like that. Can't really upgrade to 8 :|

Comment: @Jake the query you posted does not return the column `subject`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select *
from student s inner join 
     (select sm.*,
             row_number() over (partition by student_id order by marks desc) as seqnum
      from student_marks sm
     )
     on s.student_id = sm.student_id and sm.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: OP says he cannot use with so he may not be on a version (8 or above) which will allow him to use window functions either.

Comment: On the other hand, if the OP needs functions that have been available in MySQL since 2017, it's reasonable to expect they should upgrade to a version that supports those functions.

Comment: @Bill Karwin - you aren't prepared to countenance questions where posers are not in a position to upgrade?

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there:

```
select * from
student s
inner join student_marks sm1
  on s.student_id = sm1.student_id
inner join (
    select student_id, max(marks) as marks from student_marks group by student_id
) sm2
on sm1.student_id = sm2.student_id and sm1.marks = sm2.marks;
```

Then you can use `sm1` to get the other columns from the respective row with the max marks.

Note this may find ties, if there are multiple rows in `student_marks` that match the max value for marks.

This is why window functions are so useful.

Another solution I've used prior to MySQL 8.0 involves a "tiebreaker" column. Any column that is guaranteed to be distinct within the set of rows that match the max marks will work, but the primary key is a typical choice. Assume the primary key of this table is `id`.

```
select * from
student s
inner join student_marks sm1 on s.student_id = sm1.student_id
left outer join student_marks sm2 on s.student_id = sm2.student_id 
  and (sm1.marks < sm2.marks or sm1.marks = sm2.marks and sm1.id < sm2.id)
where sm2.student_id IS NULL;
```

The way this works is to check to see if a row `sm2` exists that has greater marks, or if not greater, then the `id` is greater. If no such row exists, then `sm1` must be the row with the greatest marks. This happens when the OUTER JOIN returns NULL for the columns of `sm2`.

This solution also works if you don't care about ties, just remove the term for `id`:

```
select * from
student s
inner join student_marks sm1 on s.student_id = sm1.student_id
left outer join student_marks sm2 on s.student_id = sm2.student_id 
  and sm1.marks < sm2.marks
where sm2.student_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, how can I use s.marks! There is no column with name marks in student table.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. I've edited the query above to show how to solve it.

Comment: The attempt that I made is already giving me the desired result. But that is running slow as there is a group by function before join. I'm looking for something which doesn;t involve group by and use the join functionality at max.

Comment: I have provided a solution that does not use group by.

Answer (score 1):

Use `NOT EXISTS` to get the highest `marks` of each student:

```
select sm.*
from student_marks sm
where not exists (select 1 from student_marks where student_id = sm.student_id and marks > sm.marks)
```

Then join the table `student`:

```
select s.*, t.subject, t.marks
from student s
inner join (
    select sm.*
    from student_marks sm
    where not exists (select 1 from student_marks where student_id = sm.student_id and marks > sm.marks)
) t on t.student_id = s.student_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qPdJWi4JhZSZ9fjZRGKhu7/0).
Results:

```
| student_id | name   | Age | subject      | marks |
| ---------- | ------ | --- | ------------ | ----- |
| S1         | Biden  | 15  | Trigonometry | 90    |
| S2         | Jordan | 16  | Geology      | 75    |
```